# Can Inquisitors use Determination twice/day at 3rd level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Inquisitors](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) have an archtype [Preacher](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/paizo---inquisitor-archetypes/preacher) that allows them to effect rerolls in certain circumstances.  They gain this ability (called "Determination") at 3rd level, and may use it once/day.

Preachers gain additional uses of Determination by sacrificing teamwork feats:

> Whenever the preacher could select a bonus teamwork feat (at 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th, 15th, and 18th level), she can instead choose to increase her number of uses per day of this ability by one.

Does this mean that at 3rd level, by sacrificing her first teamwork feat, a Preacher could have two uses of Determination per day?  Or does gaining the ability at 3rd level *imply* that you sacrifice the feat for the once/day use?

Comment: I find it very hard to see an alternative interpretation. What is the one you thought of? I suggest you add that to your question, to allow some meatier answers.

Comment: @Ernir: sure, edited.  It seems to me that the initial once/day use might be the result of sacrificing that first feat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It says you can: they explicitly mention the 3rd level teamwork feat as an option for getting extra uses.

#### Do you have to sacrifice a teamwork feat? Is doing so required just to make it once per day?

Nope! By default, just for having the ability, you get one use/day. Note that Determination says you can use it once per day with *no* catches, *no* tricks, *no* trade-off: you just get it, like any other ordinary once per day ability.

> ### Determination (Ex)
>
> At 3rd level, the preacher is a person of few words on the battlefield, but those words hold great power and authority. Once per day, the inquisitor can use this ability to create one of the following effects. Each is a free action to use.

Sacrificing your teamwork feats is something you can *optionally* do for *extra* uses. At third level, you receive Determination (which you can use once per day), and a teamwork feat. If you want, you can sacrifice your teamwork feat to be able to use Determination twice per day - or you can just keep the feat.